# Spring simetimes throw Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

I'm using Spring in my project (Spring MVC, Spring data, Spring security) but sometimes, maybe after inactive time but I'm not sure, I recieve this exception for example into my login page, then if I retry it works.
DO you know what it could be? If you need more information (configuration or other files I can write them)

```
2016-07-19 09:50:56 - org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:225)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:368)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:308)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:351)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the exception catched by chrome debug

[image]

This is my login page

```
<body class="hold-transition fixed login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <b>Sign in</b>
        </div>
        <!-- /.login-logo -->
        <div class="login-box-body">
            <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <div th:if="${param.error}">
                    <script>
                        notifyMessage("Invalid username and password!", 'error');
                    </script>
                </div>
<!--                <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                    <script>
                        notifyMessage("You have been logged out!", 'error');
                    </script>
                </div> -->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input id="username" name="username" type="text"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Username"> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Password"> <span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                        <button id="signinButton" type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
            </form>

            <div >
                <img th:src="@{/static/assets/dist/img/fca login.jpg}" class="img-responsive" alt="FCA">
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.login-box-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-box -->
</body>
```

and this is my security class where I authenticate user

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration implements
    AuthenticationProvider {

        @Autowired
        private UserServices userServices;
        @Autowired
        LdapServices ldapServices;

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
            String name = authentication.getName();
            String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            boolean isFind = ldapServices.ldapSearch(name, password);                           
            if (isFind){
                com.domain.User user = userServices.getByUsersEnabled(name);
                if (user!=null){
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+user.getRole().getRole()));  
                }
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
            }           
            else return null;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationConfiguration);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Autowired
        RoleServices roleServices;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            List<Role> roles = roleServices.getRoles();
            //Retrieve array of roles(only string field without id)
            String[] rolesArray = new String[roles.size()];
            int i=0;
            for (Role role:roles){
                rolesArray[i++] = role.getRole();
            }

            http
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/client/**")
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)/
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            //Exclude send file from authentication because it doesn't work with spring authentication
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/client/file").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasAnyRole(rolesArray)
            .and()
            .httpBasic();   
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        RoleServices roleServices;

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
            //Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS files.
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/static/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {         
            List<Role> roles=roleServices.getRoles();
            //Retrieve array of roles(only string field without id)
            String[] rolesArray = new String[roles.size()];
            int i=0;
            for (Role role:roles){
                rolesArray[i++] = role.getRole();
            }
            http
            .authorizeRequests() //Authorize Request Configuration
            .anyRequest().hasAnyRole(rolesArray)//.authenticated()
            .and()//Login Form configuration for all others
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll();
//          .and()
//          .sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html").maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/sessionExpired.html");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: log the full request uri and the error find you will

Comment: I have a question. you use security? and login use to process ajax rest?